Recursively search entire location including inside zip files for file match
I was recently looking for a json file from a very old project of mine. I think it might be on one of my many older external drives, but I have no idea which one, and where it would be on there, whether I put it in a zip or other archive back then first, etc. I have too much other files (and plenty of junk) on there to search for it manually.
How do I search for all .json files within a drive on Windows, such that it also looks into zip files? While I might have plenty of irrelevant json files too, if I filter it down to that I could do the rest manually. Windows Search, I believe, does not look into zip files and is just generally pretty bad.
